# Why is this code always return "[*] Exception! Exiting!"?

Tags: python, networking

This code is from the black hat python book but for the sake of this question I'll have the code in a pastebin link: [here](http://pastebin.com/E98XChyU)

Every time I use the code (`cd C:\Python27; nethacking.py -t google.com -p 80`) 
it sometimes take up to five minutes to return the error or it will just keep running, outputting nothing and only ending if I press `control-c`.

I'm on Windows 10 on and my computer model is the ASUS-F553M though that probably won't help.

Thanks for viewing my question.

Comment: Try debugging the error and printing out the exception. On line 158 from your pastebin, change that line to `except Exception as e:`. Then, within that except block, have it print out the exception by using `print(e)`

Comment: It still seems to run forever

Comment: Ciaran Walker, the above comment should help you narrow down the cause for the thrown exception, not be the remedy itself. What @qwertyuip9 suggested is about getting a handle on the exception with the name 'e', doing such, you can get all the Details on that specific exception. Thought I should clarify.